# I want to be able to shuffle questions on each click of the shuffle button

Tags: php, html, mysql, shuffle

**HTML**

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="254" border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td width="185" height="5"><p align="left">
                <label for="textfield"></label>
                <?
                $sqlretrive = mysql_query("Select * from tb_classes");
                $recordcount =  mysql_affected_rows(); 
                ?>
                <select name="classname" id="staffid2" class="form-control" required >
                    <option value="">Select Class Name</option>
                    <? while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlretrive)){ ?>
                    <option value="<?= $row['id'] ?>">
                        <?= $row['classname'] ?>
                    </option>
                    <? }?>
                </select>
            </p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="1">
            <?
            $sqlretrive = mysql_query("Select * from tb_subjects_reg where status =1");
            $recordcount =  mysql_affected_rows(); 
            ?>
            <select name="subjectname" id="select" class="form-control" required>
                <option value="">Select Subject</option>
                <? while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlretrive)){ ?>
                <option value="<?= $row['id'] ?>">
                    <?= $row['subjectname'] ?>
                </option>
                <? }?>
                <label for="subjectname">
                </label>
                <select name="subjectname" id="subjectname">
                </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="2"><div align="right">
                <input type="submit" name="find" id="find" value="Find">
            </div></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table  class="table toggle-square" data-filter="#table_search" width="541" border="0" align="center">
    <tr align="center" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FBA774">
        <td colspan="4"><input type="submit" name="shuffle" id="shuffle" value="SHUFFLE QUESTIONS" class="form-control"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FBA774">
        <td width="182"><div align="center">Question Number</div></td>
        <td align="center" valign="bottom"><div align="center">Question</div></td>
        <td align="center" valign="bottom"><div align="center"></div></td>
        <td align="center" valign="bottom"><div align="center"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <?
    $sqlretrive = mysql_query("Select * from tb_addquestion");
    $recordcount =  mysql_affected_rows();
    $i=0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqldisplayresult)){
    $i++
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><div align="center">
                <?= $i ?>
            </div></td>
        <td width="183"><div align="center"><a href="viewquestion.php?subject=<?= $row['subject'] ?>&class=<?= $row['class'] ?>&number=<?= $row['question_number'] ?>"></a>
                <?= $row['question'] ?>
            </div></td>
        <td width="100"><div align="center"><a href="viewquestion.php?subject=<?= $row['subject'] ?>&class=<?= $row['class'] ?>&number=<?= $row['question_number'] ?>&id=<?= $row['id'] ?>">View Question</a></div></td>
        <td width="58"><div align="center"><a href="viewquestion.php?subject=<?= $row['subject'] ?>&class=<?= $row['class'] ?>&number=<?= $row['question_number'] ?>"><img src="img/edit.png" alt="" />Edit </a></div></td>

    </tr>
    <?   } ?>
    <a href="viewquestion.php?subject=<?= $row['subject'] ?>&class=<?= $row['class'] ?>&number=<?= $row['question_number'] ?>"></a></td>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <div align="right"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

**PHP**

```
<? include('inc/header.php');
     ?>

    <? 
    include("connect.php"); 
    ?>
    <?
    if (isset($_POST['shuffle'])) {
        $classname = $_POST['classname'];
        $subjectname = $_POST['subjectname'];
        $sqldisplayresult = mysql_query("Select * from tb_addquestion WHERE class = '$classname' and subject='$subjectname' and status = 1 ORDER BY RAND()");
    }
    //display score for the specified class and subject in the current or specified session and term
    if (isset($_POST['find'])) {
        $classname = $_POST['classname'];
        $subjectname = $_POST['subjectname'];

    $sqldisplayresult = mysql_query("Select * from tb_addquestion WHERE class = '$classname' and subject='$subjectname' ");
    }

    ?>
```

After I have filtered with class and subject, it shows a list of the questions.

I want my Shuffle button to work in a way that once I click on it , it automatically reshuffles and select the questions randomly from the database.

Comment: Your button will need to make an Ajax call to the server to get different questions. Basically Ajax request to call a script that will execute your select query order by rand() limit 10 or so. You can easily use jQuery to handle you Ajax requests

Answer (score 0):

So why not using `ORDER BY RAND()` the way you used it in the first request?

Another way could be to use the [shuffle()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) method in PHP after you've requested your data from the database.

In any case, if you want the shuffle to be dynamic you'll have to use Ajax, maybe with [jQuery's .ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method it'll be easier